# Umbraco XSLTsearch how to add the query string to the search results URL

Tags: url, search, xslt, query-string, umbraco

How can I add the query string to the XSLTsearch results URL?

When I click on the submit button, I would like the query string to display in the URL:

e.g **/search-results.aspx?search=red**

```
<xsl:if test="$searchBoxLocation='TOP' or $searchBoxLocation='BOTH'">
  <div class="xsltsearch_form">
    <input name="search" type="text" class="input">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$unescapedSearch"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </input>
    <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
    <input type="submit" class="submit">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$dictionaryButton-Search"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </input>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers, JV

Comment: I'm not familiar with Umbraco XSLTSearch, but in order to get query parameters into the URL typically your `<form>` needs to use the [`get method`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).  Is that possible in your case, or is that abstracted out of what your XSLT can control?

Comment: My form set in my master template is set as <form id="form1" runat="server"> which on the front end the method is "post".

Answer (score 1):

your form need to be like:

```
<form action="?">
    <!--You macro here-->
</form>
```

or just

```
<form>
    <!--You macro here-->
</form>
```

assuming you have deleted the form tag in your masterpage